# How to acess value of a particular key present in redis database using java

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am trying to access redis database through jedis in java. I am able to get connected to redis. I am not able to get the value of a particular key present in the database. The code that I am using now is

```
        Jedis jedis = new Jedis(host, port);
        jedis.auth(username, password);
        Set<String> keys = jedis.hkeys(Id);
        List<String> values = jedis.hvals(Id);
```

It is returning keys and values in an incorrect order. Is there any way to get the keys and values in correct order.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" order?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on specific field order for fields in a Redis hash

From jedis, you can try [hgetall](https://www.javadoc.io/static/redis.clients/jedis/3.7.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#hgetAll-java.lang.String-). That command retrieves each key with its associated value. So you will not face that order issue again.

- https://redis.io/commands/HGETALL
- https://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes
- https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-hashes